temporary value dropped while borrowed when read csv file
I want use rust to read and process one csv format file,the file content like:
20   java
30   rust

the rust code which encounter one error
fn main() {
    let file_name = "D:\\download\\data.csv";
    let mut counter: HashMap<&str,i32> = HashMap::new();
    for line in fs::read_to_string(file_name).unwrap().lines() {
        let parts: Vec<&str> = line.split("\t").collect();
        let count: i32 = parts.get(0).unwrap().trim().parse().unwrap();
        let name: &str = name_transformer(parts.get(1).unwrap());

        if let Some(time) = counter.get_mut(name) {
            *time+=count
        } else {
            counter.insert(name, count);
        }
    };
    println!("{:?}",counter);

}

compile error message:
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:11:17
   |
11 |     for line in fs::read_to_string(file_name).unwrap().lines() {
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
...
21 |     };
   |     - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
22 |     println!("{:?}",counter);
   |                     ------- borrow later used here
   |
help: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
   |
11 ~     let binding = fs::read_to_string(file_name).unwrap();
12 ~     for line in binding.lines() {
   |

according to compiler suggestion，the follow code works well:
fn main() {
    let file_name = "D:\\download\\data.csv";
    let mut counter: HashMap<&str,i32> = HashMap::new();
    let binding = fs::read_to_string(file_name).unwrap();
    for line in binding.lines() {
        let parts: Vec<&str> = line.split("\t").collect();
        let count: i32 = parts.get(0).unwrap().trim().parse().unwrap();
        let name: &str = name_transformer(parts.get(1).unwrap());

        if let Some(time) = counter.get_mut(name) {
            *time+=count
        } else {
            counter.insert(name, count);
        }
    };
    println!("{:?}",counter);

}

Why this code 'let binding = fs::read_to_string(file_name).unwrap();' effect variable 'counter'？

What is the question?

why variable counter not work when not use this code 'let binding = fs::read_to_string(file_name).unwrap();'

I'm still not sure I understand the question. Are you asking why the error points to counter (too)?

yes,why error points to counter?

To clarify: the error is not the usage of counter. The error is where the compiler first points at. The usage of counter is only the last nail in the coffin.

thanks,I get this line counter.insert(name, count); cause error.

Side note, the entire if contraption at the end of your for loop can be replaced with *counter.entry(name).or_default() += count;.

When you write counter.insert(name, count), you are storing a reference to the the current line. The current line is a substring of  fs::read_to_string(file_name).unwrap(), so when you are storing a reference to the current line, it is also a reference to a substring of fs::read_to_string(file_name).unwrap().
When the Rust compiler finds temporary values, it drops them as soon as the lifetime of an expression ends. So your first code sample produces the same result as:
    let binding = fs::read_to_string(file_name).unwrap();
    for line in binding.lines() {
        // ...
    }
    drop(binding);
    println!("{:?}", counter);

But counter holds a reference to binding, so you can't use counter after binding has been dropped.
By explicitly storing the binding in a variable, you are telling the Rust compiler to drop binding only at the end of the scope, so you can use counter until the end of scope.
For more info, see Rust-By-Example's scoping rules chapter, or The Rust Book's ownership chapter.
